# SQL query inner join with 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

i have three tables;

Table one - Reservations

`+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| created_id      | contract_no | rent_start_date     | rent_end_date       |
+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 050316102417112 | 1291        | 2016-03-06 22:00:00 | 2016-03-14 22:00:00 |
| 050316102417112 | 8574        | 2016-04-03 10:00:00 | 2016-04-09 20:00:00 |
+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+`

Table two - reservation_customers;

`+------------------+---------------+
| created_id       | customer_id   |
+------------------+---------------+
| 050316102417112  |             1 |
| 050316102417112  |             2 |
+------------------+---------------+`

table three - customers

`+--------------+-------------------------+--------------------+
| customers_id | customers_firstname     | customers_lastname |
+--------------+-------------------------+--------------------+
|            1 | john                    | doe                |
|            2 | john                    | doe                |
+--------------+-------------------------+--------------------+`

I need a query that will return contract_no, rent_start_date and rent_end_date from reservations and customers_firstname and customers_lastname from customers using the second table to lookup customers_id.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any help may be appreciated, but if we give you the answer without you trying something, you'll learn nothing.  Please post your query attempt in the question.

Comment: In the 3rd table, if you change `customers_id` to `customer_id` then you can use a `natural join` and simplify the whole thing, something like: `select * from reservations natural join reservation_customers natural join customers;`

Comment: Never knew about natural join, Thanks tonypdmtr.